# How to pass a parameter from C# to a PowerShell script file?

Tags: powershell

From the command line I can do.

```
.\test.ps1 1
```

How do I pass the parameter when doing this from C#?
I've tried

```
   .AddArgument(1)
   .AddParameter("p", 1)
```

And I have tried passing values in as IEnumerable<object> in the .Invoke() but $p does not get the value.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Management.Automation;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Contents of ps1 file
            //  param($p)
            //  "Hello World ${p}"

            var script = @".\test.ps1";

            PowerShell
                .Create()
                .AddScript(script)
                .Invoke().ToList()
                .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to indicate that .AddParameter("p", 1) should work.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. So far it doesn't pass through to the script.

Comment: You've probably found [this](http://www.windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-with-a-purpose-blog-36/scripting-languages/calling-powershell-from-a-net-application-137445), where Don Jones uses it and adds a scriptblock parameter

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit different.   If I called test.ps from the cmdline i could do .\test.ps1 (new-object PSObject). I'm trying to figure out how to do that in code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How's this?

```
static void Main()
{
    string script = @"C:\test.ps1 -arg 'hello world!'";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    PowerShell psExec = PowerShell.Create();
    psExec.AddScript(script);
    psExec.AddCommand("out-string");

    Collection<PSObject> results;
    Collection<ErrorRecord> errors;
    results = psExec.Invoke();
    errors = psExec.Streams.Error.ReadAll();

    if (errors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ErrorRecord error in errors)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(error.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (PSObject result in results)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(result.ToString());
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Here's a similar version that passes an instance of a DateTime

```
static void Main()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    PowerShell psExec = PowerShell.Create();
    psExec.AddCommand(@"C:\Users\d92495j\Desktop\test.ps1");
    psExec.AddArgument(DateTime.Now);

    Collection<PSObject> results;
    Collection<ErrorRecord> errors;
    results = psExec.Invoke();
    errors = psExec.Streams.Error.ReadAll();

    if (errors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ErrorRecord error in errors)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(error.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (PSObject result in results)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(result.ToString());
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how you passed any parameters to a script.

Comment: I understand your question now. I've updated my answer to show a script and passing an argument to it. The easiest way I know to do it is to include the arguments in `string` you pass `psExec.AddScript(script)`

Comment: Wasn't my question, just something I'm interested in and happened to see your answer after it was posted.

Comment: That works for strings. What if I want to pass in an instance of class?

Comment: Yup, the difference is. I was using AddScript. Your example uses AddCommand. This lets AddParameter be used as well.

Comment: Is there also a way to pass in named parameters? For now I have been using multiple AddArgument calls in the order of the given script parameters, which is a bit error prone.

Answer (score 4):

So, to make a long answer short: Use AddCommand instead of AddScript

Answer (score 3):

another way is to fill the runspace with variables.

```
    public static string RunPs1File(string filePath, Dictionary<string, object> arguments)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();

        using (Runspace space = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            space.Open();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> variable in arguments)
            {
                var key = new string(variable.Key.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray());
                space.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable(key, variable.Value);
            }

            string script = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            using (PowerShell ps1 = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps1.Runspace = space;
                ps1.AddScript(script);

                var psOutput = ps1.Invoke();

                var errors = ps1.Streams.Error;
                if (errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    var e = errors[0].Exception;
                    ps1.Streams.ClearStreams();
                    throw e;
                }

                foreach (var line in psOutput)
                {
                    if (line != null)
                    {
                        result.AppendLine(line.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Actually, the best way to do it!