# Passing the argument to the file path of PowerShellScript

Tags: c#, powershell, scripting, file-handling

Trying to pass the argument(s) or list of argument to PowerShell Script Path while executing it through C# function.

I am using a C# function to get the list of details from my script via a function that uses System.Management.Automation library to invoke powershell command. I am passing file path thus the script is working perfectly fine when it does not requires any argument, however when I need to pass them it is giving User-UnHandled Exeption.

Value in the scriptPath Variable:

```
C:\Users\<username>\source\repos\MyProject\Shell\Get-SDC.ps1 'Test - Group'
```

My function:

```
private string PowerShellExecutorStr(string scriptPath)
    {
        string outString = "";
        var shell = PowerShell.Create();
        shell.Commands.AddCommand(scriptPath);
        var results = shell.Invoke();
        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var psObj in results)
            {
                builder.Append(psObj.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
            }
            outString = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
        }
        shell.Dispose();
        return outString;
    }
```

Script:

```
param($GroupName)
<Get-ADGroup Command to fetch Details of the Group using $GroupName as Parameter>
```

outString needs to fetch the output of the PowerShell Script when the arguments are passed to it.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  You say it fails when you need to pass arguments, so surely that's the problem you need to fix?  You need to pass the $GroupName parameter?

Comment: Yes so shell.invoke() will try to execute the script at the mentioned path that is passed and script path is concatenated with the input string which is the name of the group, reflecting $GroupName in the script.

Comment: Okay - you can't add arguments to the end of the script path - that should literally be the script path and nothing else.  To add parameters, have a look at the question I'm about to link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a parameter from C# to a PowerShell script file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405384/how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-c-sharp-to-a-powershell-script-file)

Comment: Oh alright gotcha!! Thanks Archer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way that I found through Archer's link is to add argument

```
private string PowerShellExecutorStr(string script, string arg)
        {
            string outString = "";
            var shell = PowerShell.Create();
            shell.Commands.AddCommand(script);
            shell.Commands.AddArgument(arg);    // <----- Using this statement
            var results = shell.Invoke();
            ……rest of the code
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Add Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCommand.AddParameter?view=pscore-6.2.0)

```
var shell = PowerShell.Create();
shell.Commands.AddCommand(scriptPath)
              .AddParameter("ParamName", "ParamValue");
var results = shell.Invoke();
```

The above is equivelent to to following PowerShell:

```
PS> scriptPath -ParamName ParamValue
```

[Here's a breakdown in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands#addparameter)